# Intent for pdf opening in your android application

Tags: android

I am trying to open pdfs from external application in my application activity. For that I am using intents. But it is not working. My code is below

````
        String filepath = "";
        if (intent != null) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            String type = intent.getType();

            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type.endsWith("pdf")) {

                Uri file_uri = intent.getData();

                if (file_uri != null)
                {
                    filepath = file_uri.getPath();
                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filepath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    pdfView.fromFile(file).enableSwipe(true).enableAnnotationRendering(true).
                            scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this)).load();
                }
            }
        }```
````

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically

Comment: What does your `<activity>` element look like for this in the manifest? If you are advertising that you support the `content` scheme, you need to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, not `File`, to consume the content.